# Create single formula for several different lines (array) (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In the `AD` column I have this sequence of values:

```
2
3
4
```

These values refer to rows in a column on another page.

In each line in `AE` column I use this formula:

```
=IF(AD1="","",IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(INDIRECT("'Registro Geral'!O2:O"&AD1)/100,REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT("'Registro Geral'!H2:H"&AD1),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(JOIN("|",$V$1:$V$4),"||",""),"|||",""))=TRUE))))

=IF(AD2="","",IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(INDIRECT("'Registro Geral'!O2:O"&AD2)/100,REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT("'Registro Geral'!H2:H"&AD2),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(JOIN("|",$V$1:$V$4),"||",""),"|||",""))=TRUE))))

=IF(AD3="","",IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(INDIRECT("'Registro Geral'!O2:O"&AD3)/100,REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT("'Registro Geral'!H2:H"&AD3),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(JOIN("|",$V$1:$V$4),"||",""),"|||",""))=TRUE))))
```

[image]

In short, this formula is getting a running Sum of values in the other sheet based on whether or not the corresponding cell in another column of the same sheet appears in a set of values.

When I try to add `ARRAYFORMULA` so that I don't have to have a formula on each line, leaving only in `AE1`, the values that return on all lines are exactly the same value.

Test Formula Fail:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AD1:AD="","",IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(INDIRECT("'Registro Geral'!O2:O"&AD1:AD)/100,REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT("'Registro Geral'!H2:H"&AD1:AD),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(JOIN("|",$V$1:$V$4),"||",""),"|||",""))=TRUE)))))
```

Link to Spreadhseet example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qIv6KnLv-EwJQXRrk7ucuqY-XuJhkIHOCtih9FpAg6U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This looks like a pretty classic example of an XY....
http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: There's no AD column in your sheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to do a running summation on `O` based on whether the corresponding value in the `H` column appears in the Filtered values.

We can do this with a matrix multiplication using a lower-triangular matrix and the listed values, selecting which ones to zero out based on certain conditions using `IF`.

```
=ArrayFormula(MMULT(
    N(SEQUENCE(D2)>=SEQUENCE(1,D2)),
    ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
        IF(
            ('Registro Geral'!O2:O<>"")*
                IFNA(MATCH('Registro Geral'!H2:H,V:V,0)),
            'Registro Geral'!O2:O
        )/100,
        D2,
        1
    )
))
```

### Why this works

The lower-triangular matrix looks like

```
1 0 0 0 0 ... up to N columns
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1
... up to N rows
```

The Column you want to sum looks like

```
Value 1
Value 2
...
Value N
```

So when you multiply the two, you get a new matrix of  dimension N x 1:

```
Value 1
Value 1 + Value 2
...
Value 1 + ... + Value N
```

If we don't want to sum a value, then we can zero it out with a conditional so that it never gets added.

Comment: very good answer, was trying to solve this as well but stumbled into all of the indirect and offset that are not iterable by the arrayformula

Comment: Just a correction I would do is to instead of the `--` would set the `N()` function as the `--` may not be the most famous operand in google sheets

Comment: @nabais Thanks. The `INDIRECT`s threw me for a loop as well. That and the filter on a `REGEXMATCH`.

Comment: So let me see if I understood it clearly: you create the lower-triangular matrix and it will be constant every time, then you loop the array formula with the 2nd single columned matrix until it has the number of rows as the other one, and then it calculates the final product of the 2 matrixes ?

Comment: @nabais I'm not sure about "looping" on the column matrix. It's more like I just took the entire column and chopped it with the `Array_Constrain`. I did that because there were blanks, which, if I did the usual `FILTER` for non-blanks, would make the matrix too short. Not sure if there's a more efficient way to do it, but from the looks of things, it's a one-time cost anyway.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Perfect solution for my need, thank you very much for your attention and help. I'm just waiting for the minimum time to be able to approve the delivery of the Bounty promised by the question!

Comment: @BrondbyIF No problem. I should mention that you also no longer need your original `SEQUENCE` column as it has been integrated into the new formula.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I really understood this question of the sequence but I will leave it to facilitate my view on the total amount of records I have.

And one more question, in column ```Q``` I search for the results in ```'Registro Geral'!O``` if the first number in ```E``` is equal to the number in ```'Registro Geral'!P```.

Would you mind showing me on the spreadsheet how I could use a model that didn't need a formula on each line too?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz If you prefer, I can create a new question and post the link here in the comments.

Comment: @BrondbyIF All I could do is simplify your formula. I'm afraid I still don't really comprehend what it's trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Thank you very much. As I understand it, you have doubts about the reason for the use, right?

I work with investments, I make investments according to the odds, so if the odds are 5, that means that for every 1 dollar I invest, I will receive 5 dollars if it is positive.

I am separating the returns according to each odds, to analyze which ones I am more profitable and less profitable.

So I am looking to look at how much profit between 5 and 5.99, 6 and 6.99 and so on.

Comment: And I needed to separate the first decimal place as text because if I try to round the number, a value of 5.99 for example is not rounded up to the 5 place, but to 6.